# Is it possible to filter for two input values using one checkbox?

Tags: html, checkbox, input

I am using checkboxes to display and filter json data points. Is something written like the `value` below this even possible?

Example Checkbox html:

```
<input class="star" type="checkbox" value="4,4.5" id="s4" name="check" />
```

Comment: ... yes ? I think I'm confused by the question.  Assigning a value to a checkbox is possible.  If you want to dynamically display the data; you may have an answer in CSS ( https://css-tricks.com/css-content/#article-header-id-3 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my question. Maybe the question was misleading because it was a small part of a bigger project.

But, I found a quick and dirty solution that probably does not have the best syntax. Please, comment if you think I can clean it up in anyway as I am still learning.

HTML example:

```
<div class="boxes">
  <input class="star" type="checkbox" value="4" id="s4" name="4.5" />
  <label for="s4"><img src="img/4star.png"></label>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
  <input class="star" type="checkbox" value="3" id="s3" name="3.5" />
  <label for="s3"><img src="img/3star.png"></label>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
  <input class="star" type="checkbox" value="2" id="s2" name="2.5" />
  <label for="s2"><img src="img/2star.png"></label>
</div>
```

I was filtering json data that was either 4-4.5 or 3-3.5 etc. I used the input `value` and `name` to pull both instances.

Here is the code I used:

```
$('#star-filter').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
  $('input.star').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
  var $list = $('.leaflet-zoom-animated > g > circle'),
  $checked = $('input:checked');    
  if ($checked.length) {                            
    var sel = '';
    var selector = '';
    $($checked).each(function(index, element){
      sel += "[data-staralt~='" + element.name + "']";  
      selector += "[data-star~='" + element.value + "']";   
    });                        
    $list.hide();
    $('.leaflet-zoom-animated > g > circle').filter(sel).show();
    $('.leaflet-zoom-animated > g > circle').filter(selector).show();
  }
  else {
    $list.show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help if you described what you were trying to achieve in plain English.

Having a look at the checkbox type of input:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

You are able to assign value="whatever", and that value will be passed on form submission (or be accessible through javascript/jquery).

It sounds like you are trying to make some sort of rating system (I see "star" and "4, 4.5"). You could look into using another element (span?) or even a list (), styling the individual list items, and calculating the value using javascript.

Again, it would help if you could clarify what you are trying to achieve.

EDIT: On second thought, yes. You could definitely store a value like "4,4.5" in a checkbox value property. If you want to treat "4" and "4.5" as separate values I suppose you could run a .split(',') to get an array of values that were separated by commas.

Comment: I am plotting points on a Leaflet map using D3.js and a Yelp json data set. My dilemma is that I can only filter by whole numbers. But, sometimes restaurants have a 3.5 rating. My values can only be one or the other 3 or 3.5. I was hoping to find a way to combine the results so that all restaurants with a 3 rating also include the restaurants with the 3.5 ratings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery with a hidden input.

```
<script>
 $(document).on('change','#s4',function(){
  $(this).is(':checked'){
   $(this).next().val('4,4.5');
  }else{
   $(this).next().val('');
  }
 });
</script>
<input class="star" type="checkbox" id="s4"/>
<input type="hidden"name="check"/>
```